# Generate binary matrix with specific number of ones in row

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary

EDIT: I also must have the sum of each column to equal a specific number!!

I want to generate a binary NxN matrix such that each row contains a specific number of 1's without repeating rows. Example: Generate 4x4 matrix with 2 ones in each row and with the sum of the column value equals 2, that is, generate

[image]

Hence, each row is unique and has exactly 2 ones and the sum of each column is 2. A WRONG answer would be:

```
B =

 1     1     0     0
 1     0     1     0
 1     0     0     1
 0     1     1     0
```

because the sum of column 1 does not equal 2 (but 3) and the sum of column 4 does not equal 2 (but 1). Each column should add up to 2. How can I achieve the correct answer in matlab?

Comment: just comment as this is not my answer:[Roger Stafford](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/76363-changing-position-of-numbers-in-a-vector) shows a very efficient way to get all possible permutations. Even for lengths > 10. `x=[1 1 0 0];n = size(x,2); k = sum(x==1); C = nchoosek(1:n,k); m = size(C,1); B = zeros(m,n); B(repmat((1-m:0)',1,k)+m*C) = 1 `

Comment: can you explain your edit with an example?

Comment: Yes, done. I have added a WRONG example.

Comment: This reminds me of the 8-queens-problem. Perhaps this could help you: [8-queens-problem -Generating All Solutions](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2017/05/04/the-eight-queens-problem-generating-all-solutions/)

Comment: @Irreducible: I don't think it is that complicated. If the matrix is 4x4, then I need 2 ones in each row. If the matrix is 6x6, then I need 3 ones in each row, if 8x8, then 4 ones,... etc. Each row should be unique. No simple solution for that?

Comment: The queen problem also sounds very easy, here you only want one 1 per row and column (independent of the size of the Matrix). This is a combinatory problem. In your case you have more conditions which doesn't make the problem easier. The easiest what I can imagine is you generate all permutations and search brute force through all combinations for one final solution.

Comment: Related: [Number of (0,1)−matrices with exactly two 1's in each row and column](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/35019/274245)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to generate a matrix with random
permutations of a list `p = randperm(n,k)`
https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

And generate a matrix from this rows (at list with a loop)